# "as of last month" and "as of next month"

Tags: phrase-usage

In "as of last month" and "as of next month", "as of" has a different meaning?

[cambridge cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/as-of-from)

> **As of next month**, all the airline's fares will be going up.

[chinadaily](http://www.chinadaily.com.cn/a/201810/10/WS5bbd5d6ba310eff30328180e.html)

> **As of last month**, Huaye had produced goods worth almost 1.5 billion
>   yuan this year, recording about 1.1 billion yuan in sales, according
>   to data from the company.

Comment: Today, I read this "Despite targeted successes in certain areas —,  about 2,000 migrants who traveled in a caravan from Central America last year appeared to have given up their cause as of last month after being discouraged by long delays in Tijuana —,  migrants seem only to have adjusted their routes rather than turn back." and I read the "as of" again. I don't understand what confused the OP in that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "as of" means the same in both sentences - from that point in time. You can also say:

> **As of now**, my services to your charity will be free of charge.

Comment: Oh, my ... I have thought, the second means "up to last month". Now, I get the meaning. It says the company just had the ability to produce ...

Comment: It means that was when they reported their trading figures. "... had produced goods ... according to data from the company".